# How can I pull the most counted values for each level of a variable?

Tags: r, tidyverse, distinct-values

[Original dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-11-08/state_stations.csv)

I want to get only the most counted values of a level in a variable? My code ise below:

`

```
a <- format_separated %>% 
  group_by(state, format) %>% 
  summarise(total = n(),
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(desc(total))
```

`

| State | Format | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | Public radio | 25 |
| New York | Country | 17 |
| Ohio | Classical | 14 |
| New York | Public radio | 12 |

(1015 entries)

But I just want to get the most counted format of each single state like this:

| State | Format | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | Public radio | 25 |
| New York | Country | 17 |
| Ohio | Classical | 14 |
| Florida | Public radio | 11 |

(46 entries)

The final dataset I intend to obtain should include the 50 states of the US and should not be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-11-08/state_stations.csv")

df %>%  
  count(state, format, sort = TRUE) %>%  
  group_by(state) %>%  
  slice_head() %>%  
  arrange(-n)

# A tibble: 50 x 3
# Groups:   state [50]
   state      format      n
   <chr>      <chr>   <int>
 1 Texas      Country   148
 2 California Variety   116
 3 Kentucky   Country    71
 4 Tennessee  Country    68
 5 Missouri   Country    66
 6 Minnesota  Country    62
 7 Illinois   Country    59
 8 New_York   Country    52
 9 Arkansas   Country    51
10 Georgia    Country    51
# ... with 40 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```